# Is there any way to view maps in "perspective" with ArcGIS (ArcMap do not)?

Tags: spatial-database, spatial-view

I need to work with ArcGis by the amount of data that I use and the answers I need, but would like to see my maps in perspective and I can't find a way. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcMap can only show plane maps. If you want to view your data in 3D you have to buy [3D Analyst Extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/3danalyst) ($ 2500 in US).

Comment: @Apa - if the answer answered your question, you can click mark the answer as "accepted" (klick on the grey checkmark on the left side of the answer). Or do you need more information?

Comment: Thank you @Jens. I'm new and didn't know that. ;)